# how do I set as an option d=identicon when using the gravatar plugin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gravatar

I have set up the gravatar RoR plugin successfully (yeah!) but when someone does NOT have a gravatar account, I want it to display the identicon, which I guess shows up when d=identicon in the gravatar URL...but since I am using the plugin, I am basically saying gravatar_for (user) so...is there a way to add that value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using [gravtastic](http://github.com/chrislloyd/gravtastic/tree/master) you can probably get it to work by doing the following in your model

```
is_gravtastic, :default => "identicon"
```